# dropzone.js isn't starting to transfer files even with autoProcessQueue set to true

Tags: dropzone.js

I've set up a simple dropzone form to accept only images with the following settings:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" class='dropzone' id='assetAdd' enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<script>
  Dropzone.options.assetAdd = {
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 10,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,*.jpg,*.gif,*.png"};
</script>
```

However while I can only select image files and when I do I see a thumbnail and no errors in the JavaScript console the transfer never begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mistake cost me about 4 productive hours, so I hope this can help others who end up in the same trap. The problem comes from a misconfiguration of `acceptedFiles`, the correct configuration should be:

acceptedFiles: "image/*,.jpg,.gif,.png"

A reference to why can be seen in the source of dopzone (on [line #176](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.coffee#L176)):

> A file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (E.g.: ".jpg,.png,.doc")
>   ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept))

File extensions must start with a `.` and do not work like wildcard selectors on a command line.

Comment: How it took "4 productive hours" ? When you posted the question and answer almost at the same time !

Comment: I posted the question and answer after I figured out what was wrong :) I spent most of the 4 hours looking at StackOverflow trying to see if anyone had the same issue, turned up nothing so I thought I'd share

Comment: Also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ :)

Comment: You do not need to add the "image/*" and also without "\*" before any extension. In the start, Dropzone say's "This is a comma separated list of mime types **or** file extensions", if you will add "image/*" in the start it will let the user choose any image type and not only ".jpg,.gif,.png". you need to fix it to `acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.gif,.png"`.